# EditText in DialogFragment: How to limit to single line and show "Search" icon at the keyboard?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-dialogfragment, android-keypad, dialogfragment

I have prepared [a simple test project at GitHub](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/q42/WordGame) for my question:

[image: screenshot]

In a word game for Android I would like to offer the user a possibility to check, if a word is available in the game dictionary - by displaying a `DialogFragment` with a single `EditText`.

Here is a code excerpt from the custom [FindWordDialogFragment.java](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q42/WordGame/app/src/main/java/de/afarber/wordgame/FindWordDialogFragment.java):

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final EditText editText = new EditText(getContext());
    editText.setMaxLines(1);
    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v,
                                      int actionId,
                                      KeyEvent event) {

            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {

                String word = editText.getText().toString();
                mListener.findWord(word);
                dismiss();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
        .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setTitle(R.string.find_word_title)
        .setView(editText, 16, 16, 16, 16)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.find_word_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String word = editText.getText().toString();
                    mListener.findWord(word);
                }
            }
        )
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.find_word_cancel, null)
        .create();
}
```

Unfortunately, there are 2 problems (marked by red arrows in the above screenshot):

1. There are still several lines of text in the `EditText`
2. And there is no "Search" icon displayed at the keyboard

Can anybody please help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to find `setSingleLine(true)` works more consistently than `setMaxLines(1)`.

For search, try adding `editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH)`. Your code handles the search event when it receives one, but that doesn't tell it to send it in the first place.

Comment: Alternatively, in xml: android:singleLine="true"